# Checking meta_value in a loop with multiple choices

Tags: wordpress, loops, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I can't get this to work correctly.

I want to loop through all child pages of the current page, find all the pages that have a 'status' of 'available' or 'coming Soon'.

The status field is an Advanced Custom Field select dropdown that has 6 options but I only want ones with available or coming soon.

Here is my current code. Its currently returning all child pages and ignoring the array check.

```
<?php $children = get_pages( array( 
                'child_of' => $post->ID, 
                'post_type' => 'property',
                 array(
                    'key' => 'status',
                    'value' => array('Available','Coming Soon'),
                    'compare' => 'IN'
                 )
                ));?>
```

if I do -

```
<?php $children = get_pages( array( 
                'child_of' => $post->ID, 
                'post_type' => 'property',
                'meta_key' => 'status',
                'meta_value' => 'Available',

                ));?>
```

Then it rightly returns just the 'available' posts but I want available and coming soon...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the meta_query and you should use get_posts

```
<?php 

  $children = get_posts( 
    array( 
        'child_of' => $post->ID, 
        'post_type' => 'property',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'status',
                'value' => array('Available','Coming Soon'),
                'compare' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    )
  );

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Its still returning all child pages and ignoring the array check. Any other ideas?